# How to draw a surface in matlab by using three vectors?

Tags: matlab

I have three vectors:

```
a (1500 x 1)
b (1500 x 1)
c (1500 x 1)
```

When I use `surf(a, b, c)` then it gives the following error:

> Error using surf (line 57)
>
> Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

I have to draw the surface for these three vectors. How can i do this?

Comment: Error message clearly tells what the problem is. In your case, `c` is a vector. It should be a matrix instead!

Answer (score 0):

That is not clear how you try to draw surface: if you mean `a` is a first dimension `(1500*1)`, `b` - the second `(1500*1)`, so third dimension have to be `(1500*1500)` - values for each point of grid `a*b`.

The solution: you have to form 1 of them of `1500*1500` size:

```
a = 1:1500;
b = 1:1500;
c = ones(1500);
surf(a,b,c);
```

[image]